# Bootstrap 3 navigation bar right margin is not supposed to be -15px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my web page I have a Bootstrap 3 navbar:

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Teachlab</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
```

The problem is that navigation is to close to the edge of the screen. If I remove *navbar-fixed-top* from the navigation bar, it's working as I want.

Any hints?

Comment: How about removing navbar-fixed-top? Or adding some extra margin in CSS to that class?

Comment: Inspect the CSS and debug the CSS rules applied to it.  If remove `.navbar-fixed-top` fixes the issue, it's most likely a definition applied to that class which you have to either remove or override.

Comment: @Kenneth I was just wandering if it's the newbie mistake.

Comment: @Axel can you please take a look at my answer?

Comment: .navbar-right goes on the .collapse container not on the ul. Posted example of correct structure and sample.

Answer (score 15):

Use .container-fluid as of 3.1.1.

The structure is not correct. .navbar-right goes on the .collapse container not on the ul.

**SAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/eQIROsE/2/edit**

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> 
  </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  If you look at the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) and at the source of http://getboostrap.com itself, the .navbar-right class is shown on the ul.

Comment: If you use a .container that is true but he doesn't have a .container, so you stick it on the collapse or it pushes all the way to the edge.

Comment: Your comment was enough for me to figure out an even more complex problem, but the solution should work here as well. In short, you can simply enclose your navbar-header and sister elements in a container (I'm using a fluid-container)

Comment: Yes, this was before 3.1 so container-fluid didn't exist

Answer (score 13):

I ended up with overriding following:

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

But maybe there's another solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's broken and [won't fix](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18362#issuecomment-160499545) in `3.x`. Hack it.

```
.navbar-right {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this could be

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't see why you'd have two .navbar-nav.navbar-right. Just wrap the navs in .navbar-right instead.

```
<div class="navbar-right">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">...</ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">...</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue today!
According to Bootstrap doc `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` is correct.

Like you, I solved the problem by setting the nav navbar-nav navbar-right margin-right to 0px without noticing unwanted effects.

Notice that the margin-right value of **.navbar-text**.navbar-right:last-child is 0px while **.navbar-nav**.navbar-right:last-child margin-right value is -15px... Bizarre?

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13325

Answer (score 0):

My not so elegant solution, but does the job very quickly, add a last list item;

```
<li><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with

> margin-right: -15px;

in .navbar-right then just add in your css styles

```
.navbar-right {
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
```

and if this still doesn't work clear your browser from all history when your webstie was running and debug it again. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

**(Fixed in asp.net mvc)**
I had the same problem in asp.net mvc c#, the way i fix it was by going to Contents/bootstrap.css  i located the `.navbar{}` class and i add it a padding of 5 px,that worked for me.

[Heres how it looks when you find it..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc3vH.png)